# How do I see that a device is mounted with `exec` option using either mount or /proc/mounts?

Tags: debian, files, mount, devices

I've mounted a cdrom device with `mount -o exec /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0`, since I couldn't execute files on it, when the drive was initially mounted by the virtual machine.

Now, when I run `cat /proc/mounts`, I get the following output:

`/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0 iso9660 ro,relatime 0 0`

It seems that the drive is still mounted read-only, but now I can execute files on it without errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/mounts` and `mount` don’t show settings which are included in the default settings, so you can assume that an entry which doesn’t show the contrary is using [the defaults](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#FILESYSTEM-INDEPENDENT_MOUNT_OPTIONS) (see the documentation there for `defaults`):

> `rw`, `suid`, `dev`, `exec`, `auto`, `nouser`, and `async`.

If `/proc/mounts` doesn’t list `noexec`, then the file system is mounted with the `exec` permission.