# Is it normal for tune2fs default mount options to not appear in mount output?

Tags: linux, ext4, ssd, util-linux, e2fsprogs

I have an SSD with 2 partitions formatted with ext4. On the second partition, I enabled `discard` as a default option at the filesystem level with this command:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -o discard /dev/sda2
tune2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2 | grep 'mount options'
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl discard
```

I also added the `discard` option to both partitions on `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda2 /     ext4 rw,relatime,discard,stripe=8191 0 1
/dev/sda1 /boot ext4 rw,relatime,discard,stripe=8191 0 2
```

However, when I look into the output of `mount`, only the one without the `discard` fs-level default mount option seems to have it enabled:

```
$ mount | grep '^/dev'
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=8191)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,stripe=8191)
```

I notice that the other options mentioned by `tune2fs` are also not mentioned.

So, can I trust that `discard` is enabled in the current mount of `/dev/sda2` despite `mount` not mentioning it? Is there some way to verify it? I mean, even `tune2fs`'s output isn't about the current mount.

EDIT: I should mention that I also tried mounting with `mount -o discard` in the command line and it still doesn't show in `mount` output:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -o discard /dev/sda1
tune2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
$ sudo umount /boot
$ sudo mount -o discard /boot
$ mount | grep sda1
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=8191)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`/proc/mounts` and `mount` don’t show settings which are included in the default settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/525787/86440), including defaults set in the file system options using `tune2fs`, so unfortunately this is normal.

To determine whether `discard` is enabled, you need to check the defaults, check the `mount` options, and combine the two sets of information.